# \part and text on same page in book documentclass

Tags: page-breaking, books, parts, text

I wonder how to get `\part` and `text` on same page with `book` `documentclass`. Thanks for any help.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[english]{babel} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}     
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\part{Test1}

\lipsum[1-5]

\part{Test2}

\lipsum[2-6]

\end{document}
```

Comment: `\part` uses either a `\cleardoublepage` or a `\clearpage` -- you have to get rid of them. I am pretty sure this has been asked already here on TeX.SE

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you need is the `titlesec` package.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[english]{babel} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}     
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleclass{\part}{top}
\titleformat{\part}[display]
  {\huge\bfseries\centering}{\partname~\thepart}{0pt}{}
\titlespacing*{\part}{0pt}{40pt}{40pt}

\begin{document}
    \part{Test1}
    \lipsum[1-5]
    \part{Test2}
    \lipsum[2-6]
\end{document}
```

[image]